# ¿Cómo generar un código QR con librería kjua utilizando el contenido de una variable?

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es crear un `QR` con unos datos sacados de una variable (la cual mete el usuario).

```javascript
var VARIABLE = "datos metidos por el usuario";

var qr = kjua({text: 'VARIABLE', size: 100});

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(qr);
```

No sé si entendéis lo que digo, y necesito la librería `kjua`, pero no sé si permite esa opción...

Answer (score 1):

Literalmente con el código que adjuntas funciona, solo que para que te genere el `qr` con el contenido que tienes guardado en la variable, debes eliminar las comillas de `'VARIABLE'`:

```js
var VARIABLE = "https://hmpg.net/";
var qr = kjua({text: VARIABLE, size: 100});
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(qr);
```

```html
<script src="https://larsjung.de/kjua/latest/kjua-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Te adjunto otro ejemplo interactivo con un input. En este caso, cuando el usuario presione el botón, se generará un código `qr` de lo que haya en escrito en el `input`:

```js
var qrContainer = document.querySelector('#qr-container')
var input = document.querySelector('input')

function generarQR () {
    var VARIABLE = input.value;
    var qr = kjua({text: VARIABLE, size: 150});
    qrContainer.innerHTML = "";
    qrContainer.appendChild(qr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://larsjung.de/kjua/latest/kjua-0.9.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="https://es.stackoverflow.com">
<button onclick="generarQR()">Generar QR</button>

<div id="qr-container"></div>
```

Para más detalles, y visualizar graficamente el QR generado, visita este [editor interactivo de kjua](https://larsjung.de/kjua/latest/demo/) y revisa [las opciones disponibles](https://larsjung.de/kjua/) de configuración que se admiten.